# Understanding express data flow and call backs

Tags: node.js, express

I have a file called weather.js that looks like this

```
var request = require('request');
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.getWeather = function (cb){
    request('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/apiKey/43.0796,-89.3758', function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
       console.log(error);
      }
      else if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("forcast io response received");
        return body;
      }
    });
};
```

and an express routes file:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 var weather = require("../models/weather.js")


 /* GET home page. */
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('index', { weather: weather.getWeather() });
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

I know my getWeather() function works because if I console.log(body) the JSON string is printed, but it is not rendered in my browser. What I'm not really understanding is how the async pattern works. I'm thinking that the JSON is not printed because the webpage is rendered before the function is fired/completed. How can I use a callback to render the data from the api call once data is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do `return body` in this code:

```
else if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("forcast io response received");
        return body;
      }
```

If you use `Promise`, you can write code like this:

```
'use strict';

var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.getWeather = function() {
    return Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/apiKey/43.0796,-89.3758', function (error, res, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                console.log("forcast io response received");
                resolve(body);
            }
        }
    });
}



var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var weather = require("../models/weather.js")


 /* GET home page. */
 router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    weather
        .getWeather()
        .then(function(body){
            res.render('index', { weather: body });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            res.end(error);
        });
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I'm just learning node so sorry if this is a silly question, so why use a promise here instead of a callback? I would mark this right, but I'm getting "undefined is not a promise" in weather.js with what is above. I haven't been able to figure out why just yet

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to change it to "return new promise"

Answer (score -1):

```
var request = require('request');
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.getWeather = function (cb){
     request('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/apiKey/43.0796,-89.3758', function (error, response, body) {
         if (error) {
               console.log("Error");return;
          }
          else if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            cb(body);
          }
     });
};

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var weather = require("../models/weather.js")
/* GET home page. */
 router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    weather.getWeather(function(body){
            res.render('index', { weather: body });
        })
 });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: How to access `res` in your second method?

Comment: Is it, necessary to use promise, as i can achieve result by the above code ?